# Remove whitespaces that are not inside quotes

Tags: python, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Regular expression must strip whitespace except between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609596/python-regular-expression-must-strip-whitespace-except-between-quotes)

I need to remove all whitespaces in a file that are not inside single or double quotes (i.e. not in a string).

I've found this solution
[Python Regular expression must strip whitespace except between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609596/python-regular-expression-must-strip-whitespace-except-between-quotes)

but that works only for double quotes

Comment: Have you tried to adapt it to single quotes?

Comment: What should happen if single quote is nested within double quote?

Comment: Stack overflow works best when you ask questions about code you've written, rather than just asking for someone to write code for you.

Comment: if single quotes are nested inside double quotes or double quotes are nested in single quotes the whitespaces must not be removed (in the entire string)

Answer (score 4):

Remove whitespace outside quotes:

```py
import re

parts = re.split(r"""("[^"]*"|'[^']*')""", text)
parts[::2] = map(lambda s: "".join(s.split()), parts[::2]) # outside quotes
print("".join(parts))
```